# Freeing a dynamically allocated 2d array only freeing first two rows

Tags: c, dynamic-memory-allocation, free, dynamically-generated

So I have a programm where I create a dynamic 2 d array with the following function.

```
char **get2dArray(int n, int m)
{
  {
    char **p = (char **)calloc(sizeof(char *), n);

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
      p[i] = (char *)calloc(m, sizeof(p[0]));
    }

    return p;
  }
}
```

The function is filled with some data after its creation. It basically holds a sentence in every 2d_arr[i].

```
void getSentencesWithNumber(int sentence_total, char **sentences_seperated_2d)
{
  printf("Ihre Wahl:  Nr. | Satz\n-----+----------------------------------------\n");
  for (int i = 0; i < sentence_total; i++)
  {
    printf("   %d | %s\n", i + 1, sentences_seperated_2d[i]);
  }
}
```

I print the sentences with the above function.

```
Ihre Wahl:  Nr. | Satz
-----+----------------------------------------
   1 | A paragraph is a series of related sentences developing a central idea, called the topic.
   2 | Try to think about paragraphs in terms of thematic unity: a paragraph is a sentence or a group of sentences that supports one central, unified idea.
   3 | Paragraphs add one idea at a time to your broader argument.
```

above is an example to how a print would look.
I wanted to delete a sentence from the array however I was unsure how that would work so I tought maybe freeing the current 2d array and making a new one with one less sentence would work. However if I use the free and print my array again it looks kinda like this:

```
Ihre Wahl:  Nr. | Satz
-----+----------------------------------------
   1 | (null)
   2 | 
   3 | Paragraphs add one idea at a time to your broader argument.
```

Above, the array was freed right after it was filled. And than the print function was called from another function. The output is the same if I

```
for (int i = 0; i < sentence_total; i++)
{
free(sentences_seperated_2d[i]);
}
free(sentences_seperated_2d);
```

Above is the free I used.

Any idea on how only the first 2 sentences get deleted here and not the others? For me it makes no sense. Also even if there is more sentences only the first two are emptied.

Thanks, I hope I made my problem clear.

Comment: `free` does not "empty" the contents. It just returns the memory to the allocator. Never access freed memory. Doing so results in Undefined Behaviour and you cannot have any expectation on what the result will be.

Comment: `p[i] = (char *)calloc(m, sizeof(p[0]));` is wrong, this gives `m * sizeof (char*)`. You should be using `p[i] = calloc(m, 1);` or equivalent. Not sure if it's the root cause of your problem but it's a bug.

Comment: `free()` is technically a declaration that the pointed object is never ever going to be accessed again. So the compiler/runtime-environment can do whatever it considers suitable with object's memory. Any violation of this declaration results in UB.

Comment: You have not stated what behavior you expected instead, so we do not know which mistaken idea you have. Did you expect the memory to contain zeros after `free` was called? `free` is not required to and generally does not deliberately zero the memory. (There might be debugging features that can be turned on to do this, and `free` might alter some of the memory to use it for its own database purposes.) Did you expect the memory to be inaccessible after `free` was called?  `free` is not required to and generally does not unmap the virtual memory (although it might for large allocations)…

Comment: Did you expect the pointer to be set to null after `free` was called? `free` cannot change the actual object used to pass it an address. (However, compiler optimization can cause effects as if the object were changed, but, in this regard, the formal semantics of the C language render the pointer invalid, not null.)

Comment: Oh, I was under the expression that when the allocated memory is freed, the content it holds would naturally be deleted from the memory. What I wanted to achieve was to actually free the my2d array and make the pointer to that array point to a new one. Is that possible? (Also after freeing I set the pointer to NULL and that also didnt change anything so I was curious to why the pointer was still pointing to that data)

Comment: @Lundin Why one?

Comment: @chrisbasmaci `char` has size 1 byte by definition. It can never have a different size.

Comment: @EricPostpischil What I basically want to delete a row from my 2d array, and add columns. Whats the best approach for that?

Comment: @Lundin So multiplying with char would also work right.

Comment: @chrisbasmaci `sizeof(char)` is always 1 if that's what you mean.

Comment: Multiplying by `sizeof(char)` would work, but it is pointless since, as said, it is `1` by definition (all sizes are in units of `sizeof(char)`, so it cannot possibly ever have any other value than that). Multiplying by `sizeof(*p[0])` would be a more sensible alternative if you don't wish to hardcode the type.

Comment: @Lundin hey I tried multiplying with one but that doesnt work, multyplying the col with 11 is the only number it works with, any idea why?

Comment: @chrisbasmaci Because you have a bug somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

I did not understand if you have to use a 2d array, or is the solution you have chosen. Since you intend to delete what you printed, the array does not seem to be the right data type for your need. I would advise you to use a double linked lists. Create a recursive structure like:

```
struct INFO {
    int id;
    char *description;
    struct INFO *parent_node;
    struct INFO *next_node;
}
struct INFO *root = malloc(sizeof(struct INFO));
```

so when you want to delete the entry just copy the current next_node to that of the previous node (which contained the address of the current node), then free the current node.
Just an example of how to feed the list:

```
for(;;)
{
    id  = get_id();
    des = get_des();
    if(des == NULL)
        break;
    last->next_node = malloc(sizeof(struct INFO));
    last->next_node->parent_node = last;
    last = last->next_node;
    last->id = id;
    last->description = des;
    last->next_node = NULL;
}
```

To simplify your tests I add the 2 functions I use. Everything was written inaccurately, you will have to test the result of the allocations (even if I don't understand why if you don't test the result of a malloc in C you commit sin while in C++ I see 'new' untested everywhere and nobody complains).

```
int get_id()
{
    int id;

    printf("\nid: ");
    scanf("%d", &id);
    getchar();
    return id;
 }

char *get_des()
{
    int i, c, s_ch = sizeof(char);
    char *des = malloc(1 * s_ch);
    printf("\ndescription: ");
    for(i = 0; (c = getchar()) != '\n'; i++)
    {
        des[i] = c;
        des = realloc(des, 1 * s_ch);
    }
    des[i] = '\0';
    if(!strcmp(des, ""))
    {
        free(des);
        des = NULL;
    }
    return des;
}
```

to print the list:

```
for(p = root; p != NULL; p = p->next_node) /* show list */
{
    printf("\nid: %d description: %s", p->id, p->description);
}
```

to search and delete:

```
for(p = root; p != NULL && p->id != 2; p = p->next_node); /* find */

if(p != NULL) /* show and delete */
{
    printf("\n\nfound: id: %d description: %s", p->id, p->description);
    if(p->parent_node != NULL)
        p->parent_node->next_node = p->next_node;
    else
        root = p->next_node;
    free(p);
}
```

Comment: We havent started using structs yet so I am not really familiar with them however I achieved what I wanted to do by just switching the pointers to my 2d arrays and just freeing the old arrays. It works perfectly rn however was that a bad approach or just an unfamiliar one since it will take time to allocate a new array and free it?

Comment: If you think you are spending too much time allocating you could simply move what you want to delete to the bottom of the array and translate the other fields up, then delete the fields

Comment: Oh that makes sense as well thanks